# When clicking on the [bounties] link, the view gets updated but the filter list does not

Tags: bug, new-nav

[image: Example]

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the blue <kbd>**N bounties**</kbd>  link at the top right of the nav.
2. The view updates to show only questions with bounties.
3. Click the Filter button at the left of the nav.
4. *all* is still highlighted, and *bounty* is not.

#### Extra:

1. Clicking the *bounties* entry in the filter list updates the view in the same way, and updates the list.
2. The same happens both with conjunction with other filters and sorters, as well as without any.